# How to return a function in setTimout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, dom-events

I have this code:

```js
first(1000, function() {
  alert("Hey");
});

function first(t1, a1) {
  var time1 = setTimeout(a1, t1);
  document.onmousemove = document.mousedown = document.mouseup = document.onkeydown = document.onkeyup = document.focus = function() {
    clearTimeout(time1);
    time1 = setTimeout(a1, t1);
  };
}

second(3000, function() {
  alert("hello");
});

function second(t2, a2) {
  var timetwo = setTimeout(a2, t2);
  document.onmousemove = document.mousedown = document.mouseup = document.onkeydown = document.onkeyup = document.focus = function() {
    clearTimeout(timetwo);
    timetwo = setTimeout(a2, t2);
    return first;
  };
}
```

In this code I receive 2 alerts: First the Hey and then the Hello. But as you can, once I move the mouse, everything is reset but only Hello. He does not come back and he says Hey.

I need that when you move the mouse, always return to hey and not to hello. Bone to the first function.

Do you know how I could do it? Thank you!

Comment: I think you should re-title your question; the body of the question isn't asking how to return a function, and [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) returns a _timeoutID_ — it can't return a function anyway.

Comment: After a bit of formatting it seems to be more clear. I agree you should change the title.

Answer (score 0):

You do this in one function:

```
 document.onmousemove = document.mousedown = document.mouseup = document.onkeydown = document.onkeyup = document.focus = function()
```

and then this in second function:

```
 document.onmousemove = document.mousedown = document.mouseup = document.onkeydown = document.onkeyup = document.focus = function()
```

Thus you assign the same global set then reassign it.  Set up an event listener instead

Comment: Note you call `second` second so it overwrites `first` handlers, if you cal `second` first, it will be overwritten by `first` when it is subsequently called.  So the last one called "wins"